# Android web view got refresh when display toast

Tags: android, webview, android-toast

Hi I am developing android application in which I am using  `BroadcastReceiver` and one `Activity`. In my activity I am loading `WebView`. So when I am displaying toast inside my broadcast receiver that time my `WebView` got reloaded.

```
final static BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      showToast(context, message, duration);
}
```

and inside activity

```
WebView view = new WebView(this);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
```

So whenever toast comes up it reloads my webview. Need some help. This issue not coming on all devices. But coming on some of android devices.

```
public static void showToast(Context context, String message, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, duration).show();
}
```

Comment: what are you doing in `showToast();`

Comment: dislaying simple toast message

Comment: post your show toast method.

Comment: is your webview initialized in onCreate();